# Register iBeacon using Google Proximity Beacon API

Tags: ios, postman, ibeacon, google-proximity-api

I've been trying to register an iBeacon using Google Proximity Beacon API using Google OAuth Playground, since the registration is not possible using Beacon Tools App.

`1) Signed up on Google API Console.
2) Created new Project.
3) Enabled Beacon Proximity API and Nearby API.
4) Generated API key from Credentials.
5) Provided Client ID as header ( "Authorization":BearerValue )`

https://proximitybeacon.googleapis.com/v1beta1/beacons:register?key=(API_KEY)

`{
  "advertisedId": {
    "type": "EDDYSTONE",
    "id": "T3jqVgkCAwoToQABAACAew=="
  },
  "status": "ACTIVE"
}`

The `Beacon Editor` permission for Proximity Beacon API is also provided in my account from IAM - Google API Console.

But the response I get is

`{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Unauthorized.",
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
    }
}`

Found similar posts, but none of them had a correct answer. Did anyone find a solution to this?